# Why Xcode 4 code completion is slow?

Tags: xcode4, code-completion

Is there anything to do to make code completion react faster?

I have the same issue on mac mini 2010 with 4gb Ram and on iMac 21.5 i3 2010.

I there something to set to make it work faster? or is just me that I have this problem?

Does any one have the same issue?

Answer (score 1):

I have started to experience the same issue. Initially it was fine, but over time it has begun to chug. What is particularly bad is deleting whilst the code completion dialog is open and it's trying catching up. Anyone know of anything that can be turned off in order to speed this up?

I have recently added Accessorizer, so it could be something to do with that. Will experiment and update this post.

I'm using a macbook pro core duo 2.4ghz with 8gb ram and 256gb crucial M4, so should be no problem there! Eclipse in contrast runs nicely.

Comment: Removing accessorizer has no effect. It would seem that it only slows down for classes with a high line count. Ok, perhaps a design flaw, but 500 lines in a class concerned with drawing and layout is probably quite normal. Anyone else experienced this?

Comment: Update: seems to be more specific than that. If a method has a high line count then XCode gets confused. Hopefully this will be addressed in a future release.

Comment: Ive had luck by collapsing my code lines in my large classes.  seems to help me considerably.  With all the money apple has, its a shame little bugs like like exist.  they are frustrating to say the least.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 4.5 is a bit faster at various things, including auto-complete, but it's still an issue. Sometimes when a project really starts to chug I will force it to delete 'derived data' which will cause Xcode to re-index all of the files in the project. After that things seem to be quite a bit faster, for awhile.

To delete 'derived data' click on the `Organizer` icon at the top-right corner of Xcode.
[image: Organizer Button]

Then in the Organizer window, click the `Projects` tab, then on the `Derived Data` row, click `Delete...`. After you do this wait about 5-10 seconds and Xcode should restart its indexing.
[image: Organizer Window]